# Is this the way to call ajax in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$("#export1").change(function(){
    var export2 = this.value; 
    if (export2 == "Csv") {
        alert("csv");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "export_csv.php ",
            data: "",
            success: function(data) {
                alert('data');// data is the return value from input.php
            }
        });
    }
});
```

On change I am trying to call a PHP file and it gets exported in CSV format. Can any one suggest me on this.

Comment: Don't put `data` in quotes, that will just alert the string rather than the data.

Comment: You don't need `data: ""`. That's the default.

Comment: Just `alert(data)`, that will show you the CSV file.

Comment: @Barmar can i remove data

Comment: You can remove `data: "",`

Comment: What is `input.php`? You're going to `export_csv.php`.

Comment: no its not coming

Comment: where is input .php here

Comment: Use the Network tab of Developer Tools to see the actual AJAX response.

Comment: In the comment: `data is the return value from input.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122532/discussion-between-jmr-and-barmar).

Comment: You are using Post but not posting any data. Why is this?

Comment: @mike brant I want 2 formats...if user choose csv it will get downloaded n if he choose excel it has to be downloaded...I have 2 php files for each ... thought room call those files in this way

Comment: Why use asynchronous post for this vs. window.location(...) or similar? You are not posting any data, just trying to direct browser to a download. Just plain old school HTML form using GET should suffice just fine as long as the target pages serve up correct download headers.

Answer (score 1):

2 things:

- You dont need `data: ""`. This is the default value
- You are alerting the string 'data'. Remove the quotes like this:

This code should work:

```
$("#export1").change(function(){
    var export2 = this.value; 
    if (export2 == "Csv") {
        alert("csv");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "export_csv.php",
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);// data is the return value from input.php
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: My concern is if I click on csv dropdown ...it should call php file and download the file in csv format

Comment: Aha. You cannot download a file via javascript. This is a security issue. What does the `export_csv.php` file exactly return? Could you perhaps share this file? The method you are currently using is a POST request to a php file. If this function is solely for downloading a csv file then this is not the best implementation.

Comment: It has a sql query which fetches all the records from the db

Comment: Alright, and after fetching is this converted to a csv file? If that is the case. You would simply have to redirect the user to that php file. Replace the whole ajax call with `document.location.href = "export_csv.php"`

Comment: You mean to say in this way $("#export1").change(function(){﻿ var export2 = this.value; ﻿ if (export2 == "Csv") {﻿    alert("csv");﻿    documents to.location.href="exports csv.php"    } });

Comment: Yes, but check the last line. `documents to.location.href="exports csv.php"` is not correct. It should be `document.location.href = "export_csv.php"`